# How to acquire new oauth2 AccessToken with refresh token

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, refresh-token, azure-app-registration

I Use Azure AppRegistation configured to use oauth2 code flow to authenticate my application.
This is .net 6 WebApi.
In Azure AppRegistration I have custom scope for my API: api://{clientId}/ApplicationName.

In startup.cs I have configured cookie authentication with oauth 2 using AddOauth extension.
I setup clientId, clientSecret, token endpoint and this custom scope. I also added offline_scope.

I have no problems with authenticating user, there is redirection to MS authorization endpoint, it goes back and in backchannel code is exchanged for a valid token.

I also have an refresh_token.

Later in logic of my application I'm using this access token in OBO flow, to call external service.

When i inspect this token in JWT.io, this access token has an audience the same as exposed api in Portal Azure, audience is api://{clientId}.

I'd like to acquire new access token using refresh token. I couldn't find any working library, so I'm making simple request to token endpoint providing all required parameters, grant_type, client_id, client_secret and refresh token.

The problem is that I cannot acquire working access token.
When I do not add resource parameter I got error:
"AADSTS90009: Application '{clientId}'is requesting a token for itself. This scenario is supported only if resource is specified using the GUID based App Identifier.

When I set resource in format api://{clientId} I got the same error.
When I set resource the same as clientId i can receive a new AccessToken, but this token is invalid.

It has audience simply {clientId}, and this is invalid since valid audience is api://{clientId}.

How can I get new access_token using existing refresh_token, but valid one?

Comment: Are you using MSAL.net?

Comment: No, I'm using AddOAuth AuthenticationBuilder extension method from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth assembly. There I have two schemas, Cookies and this one (i called it MSAuth). In Add authentication i have DefaultSignInScheme and DefaultAuthenticateSchame setup as Cookies and DefaultChallengeScheme = MSAuth.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I was using invalid token endpoint. (without version).
When using version /oauth2/v2.0/token everything is working.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the fix update. This would help others who encounter the same issue.